# Pivot an Array of array javascript

Tags: javascript, pivot

I am looking for converting an array of array into a Predetermined array format, by pivoting.

Currently, I am using single value as Row and Col.

But, I want to use array in both rows and cols.

Comment: Refer: https://jsfiddle.net/stiwari/yvfdgezL/

Comment: Please add what you have tried as code here. As it is now, the question got the risk of being downvoted.